# Need to set weightage for for two URL's hosted in same server

Tags: java, url, server

I got two application url's hosted in the same server.

I want to redirect 75% of the users to url1 and remaining 25% to url 2.
Can any one help me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way of doing it.
obviously it doesn't guarantee 100% accuracy but over time it should be valid.

Simply using a random number to decide where to go.

```
Random r = new Random();
double d = r.nextDouble();

if(d<=0.25){
  //use server 1
}else{
 //use server 2
}
```

Comment: Using if else is fine.. But still is there any tool we can use.? Like in the case of server balancing we use load balancer..   there is only one server but two url's

Comment: not any that I know of mate, I had once similar situation as urs. and i just did that. it **eventually** have consistent overall results.